# Visualizing High Dimensional Data at once

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I am trying to visualize my data, so that I can view all 200 columns one by one. I would like to have a more intuitive way to understand my data.

I have tried google but didn't get any help in visualizing high dimensional data. People say to use PCA but I want to visualize my raw data in columns.

[Data set Link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-transaction-prediction)

My code

```
x0=df[df["target"]==0]
x1=df[df["target"]==1]

x0_100=x0[1:300]
x1_100=x1[1:300]
x=x1_100.append(x0_100)
y=x["target"]
x=x.drop("target",axis=1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (60, 60))
j = 0
for i in x:
    plt.subplot(51,4, j+1)
    j += 1
    sns.boxplot(x=y,y=x[i])
```

[image: I am getting this type of small figures really difficult to understand]

Comment: First, please provide a data test case to help us inderstand your particular case. Second, you absolutly need to tell us what do you want to see ? Your problem looks similar to the initial problem here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55266943/7237062). In either way, when there is too much data, it seems to me to be a batter idea to use math/stats tools to peform some analysis for you first (see provided link; one can think of statistical tests, clustering, or whatever)

Comment: here i am trying to visualize boxplot of every coloum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend plotting two different box plots with a hundred columns on each:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf

df = cf.datagen.box(200)

df.iloc[:,0:100].plot(kind='box', rot=90, figsize=(14, 8))
plt.tight_layout()

df.iloc[:,100:].plot(kind='box', rot=90, figsize=(14, 8))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Box plot 1]
[image: Box plot 2]

Comment: But I want to see according to the label values. Boxplot having Target label 1 and Target label 0. By the way that good idea 100 100 coloums but not full filling my problem. Because I have Imbalance data

Comment: Can you include some sample data to help me better understand what you mean? I cannot run your code without sample data, and I can’t tell what your data structure is.